# R: Inconsistent class returned by `median()` when vector labelled with Hmisc

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column that has been labelled with the Hmisc R package. The class of the column is `c("labelled", "numeric")`. If I calculate the `median()` of the entire column, the returned median remains `c("labelled", "numeric")`.

BUT, if I calculated the `median()` in two subgroups, one median is returned with the same class, but the other is returned as class `"numeric"`. The differing classes returned is causing errors in `dplyr::summarize()`.

1. Can anyone help me understand why the class changes?
2. What can I do to resolve the issue? FYI, this code appears in the internals of a package, and I would like to avoid special coding the for variables that have been labelled with Hmisc.

```r
library(magrittr)

data <-
  structure(
    list(
      cd4_count = c(
        30, 97, 210, NA, 358, 242, 126,
        792, 6, 145, 22, 150, 43, 23, 39, 953, 357, 427, 367, 239, 72,
        61, 61, 438, 392, 1092, 245, 326, 42, 135, 199, 158, 17, NA,
        287, 187, 252, 477, 157, NA, NA, 362, NA, 183, 885, 109, 321,
        286, 142, 797
      ),
      unsuccessful = c(
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, 50L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )

# Add label to CD4 count, using Hmisc package
Hmisc::label(data$cd4_count) <- "CD4 count"

# the classes here are all the same
data$cd4_count %>% class()
#> [1] "labelled" "numeric"
data$cd4_count[data$unsuccessful == 0] %>% class()
#> [1] "labelled" "numeric"
data$cd4_count[data$unsuccessful == 1] %>% class()
#> [1] "labelled" "numeric"


# Why are the results not the same class?!?!
data$cd4_count[data$unsuccessful == 0] %>% median(na.rm = TRUE) %>% class()
#> [1] "labelled" "numeric"
data$cd4_count[data$unsuccessful == 1] %>% median(na.rm = TRUE) %>% class()
#> [1] "numeric"

# Because the classes are different, I cannot run this code
data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(unsuccessful) %>%
  dplyr::summarize_at(dplyr::vars(cd4_count), median, na.rm = TRUE)
#> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `cd4_count`.
#> x Input `cd4_count` must return compatible vectors across groups
#> i Result type for group 1 (unsuccessful = 0): <labelled>.
#> i Result type for group 2 (unsuccessful = 1): <double>.
#> i Input `cd4_count` is `(function (x, na.rm = FALSE, ...) ...`.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: an observation .. It seems like the first value of `data$cd4_count[data$unsuccessful == 1]` being `NA` might be an issue as after adding `data$cd4_count[data$unsuccessful == 1][1] = 2` it gives the expected results (btw `class(median(data$cd4_count[data$unsuccessful == 1]))` also gives the expected results)

Comment: If I delete the missing values and remove the pipe, the class is still changed. `data <- data[complete.cases(data), ]
median(data$cd4_count[data$unsuccessful == 1]) %>% class()`

Comment: another thought ... it may be due to the length of the vector after missing data is removed. Even or odd number of values get either sorted or passed to `mean` (look at `median.default`). `mean` strips the labels for both groups `mean(data$cd4_count[data$unsuccessful == 0], na.rm=TRUE)`    . (so I dont think it is to do with the pipe). So can you just add a `as.numeric` into the chain to strip the class so that they are the same?

Comment: a smaller example to see the difference in `x = c( 1, 2) ; Hmisc::label(x) = "qw"; class(median(x))` and `x = c( 1, 2, 3) ; Hmisc::label(x) = "qw"; class(median(x))`

Comment: hmisc just sets the label attribute. No idea why it is being dropped but the solution could be to test for label attributes and null them before calculating the statistic (or preemptively coerce (ifelse(class(x) %in% numeric, as.numeric(x), x).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

user20650 points out in the comments that attributes are droped and kept depending on the vector length of `x`.

When we look at the code of the `median.default` method, we can see why. If `length(x)` is an even number, then `mean` is used (inside `median`), otherwise `x` is just `sort`ed and subsetted which, unlike `mean`, doesn't remove the attributes.

```r
# lets have a look at the median.default method
function (x, na.rm = FALSE, ...) 
{
  if (is.factor(x) || is.data.frame(x)) 
    stop("need numeric data")
  if (length(names(x))) 
    names(x) <- NULL
  if (na.rm) 
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  else if (any(is.na(x))) 
    return(x[FALSE][NA])
  n <- length(x)
  if (n == 0L) 
    return(x[FALSE][NA])
  half <- (n + 1L)%/%2L
  if (n%%2L == 1L) 
    # when length is odd: attribute is kept
    sort(x, partial = half)[half] 
  # when length is even: `mean` drops attribute
  else mean(sort(x, partial = half + 0L:1L)[half + 0L:1L]) 
}
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Let's have another look at different vectors and how they behave. We can define a `keep_attr` function which will keep the attributes of the wrapped function and input.

```r
x1 <- 1
Hmisc::label(x1) = "qw"
class(median(x1)) # keeps attribute
#> [1] "labelled" "numeric"
class(mean(x1))  # drops attribute
#> [1] "numeric"

x2 <- c(1, 2)
Hmisc::label(x2) = "qw"
class(median(x2)) # uses mean
#> [1] "numeric"
class(mean(x2))
#> [1] "numeric"

x3 <- c(1, 2, NA)
Hmisc::label(x3) = "qw"
class(median(x3)) # doesn't use mean
#> [1] "labelled" "numeric"
class(mean(x3))
#> [1] "numeric"

keep_attr <- function(.f, x, ...) {
  x_att <- attributes(x)
  res <- .f(x, ...)
  attributes(res) <- x_att
  res
}

class(keep_attr(median, x2))
#> [1] "labelled" "numeric"
class(keep_attr(mean, x2))
#> [1] "labelled" "numeric"
keep_attr(median, x3, na.rm = TRUE)
#> qw 
#> [1] 1.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Update**
Regarding your dplyr problem I was now able to reproduce the problem (I first forgot to label the `cd4_count` column and thought it was a dplyr versioning issue). However, the workaround with the `keep_attr` seems to be working.

```r
library(dplyr)

data <-
  structure(
    list(
      cd4_count = c(
        30, 97, 210, NA, 358, 242, 126,
        792, 6, 145, 22, 150, 43, 23, 39, 953, 357, 427, 367, 239, 72,
        61, 61, 438, 392, 1092, 245, 326, 42, 135, 199, 158, 17, NA,
        287, 187, 252, 477, 157, NA, NA, 362, NA, 183, 885, 109, 321,
        286, 142, 797
      ),
      unsuccessful = c(
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, 50L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )

# Add label to CD4 count, using Hmisc package
Hmisc::label(data$cd4_count) <- "CD4 count"

data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(unsuccessful) %>%
  dplyr::summarize_at(dplyr::vars(cd4_count), median, na.rm = TRUE)
#> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `cd4_count`.
#> x Input `cd4_count` must return compatible vectors across groups
#> i Input `cd4_count` is `(function (x, na.rm = FALSE, ...) ...`.
#> i Result type for group 1 (unsuccessful = 0): <labelled>.
#> i Result type for group 2 (unsuccessful = 1): <double>.

data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(unsuccessful) %>%
  dplyr::summarize_at(dplyr::vars(cd4_count), ~ keep_attr(median, .x, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   unsuccessful cd4_count 
#>          <dbl> <labelled>
#> 1            0 210.0     
#> 2            1 135.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I have `dplyr` version 1.0.4 and get that error. Is it possible that you can update your `dplyr` and see if you still don't get that error?

Comment: Sure I will try! I thought you are using dplyr < 1.0 because of `summarise_at`. Is at least the workaround with `keep_attr` working?

Comment: yes! the workaround is great! I was just curious to see if this issue was fixed in one version and then not future ones.

Comment: @Mike: I was now able to reproduce the problem. It was not a dplyr versioning issue, but just me who forgot to label to column.